# Need alternative to "brave smile"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I need to describe someone giving "a brave smile" (for the benefit of others) but that phrase is such a cliche.  Is there an alternative that means the same? S.

Answer (score 2):

How about...

Kept a stiff upper lip

Kept their composure

Soldiered on

Put on a brave face

Showed courage

Took it on the chin, kept their chin up, kept their pecker up

Comment: I especially like "put on a brave face," which I guess is similar to "brave smile," but less silly.

Comment: Very similar also is 'put up a brave front' or 'put on a brave front'